# Sqlalchemy CAST equivalent of Double precision

Tags: postgresql, casting, sqlalchemy

i am interested to know the Sqlalchemy equivalent of the following command

update tablename set field1 = cast(field2 as double precision[])

so far, i tried the following with no luck

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine)
table = sqlalchemy.Table('tablename',md,autoload=true)
update_stmt = table.update(values={table.c.field1:cast(table.c.field2, **double precision[]**)})
engine.execute(update_stmt)
```

please help to resolve double precision equivalent in sqlalchemy. this is running update statement from python to postgresql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL-specific types are in [`sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-data-types).

`double precision[]` should be:

```
ARRAY(DOUBLE_PRECISION)
```